# Create custom module filebeat issue

Tags: python, elasticsearch, filebeat

I encountered problem with creating custom module in filebeat. 
I following by [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/7.3/filebeat-modules-devguide.html) and [also](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/7.3/beats-contributing.html).

When I try command `make create-module MODULE=moduleName` then I got error `Unknown targets specified: create-module MODULE=moduleName`.

Also when I try to `make update` command then I got error `This backport is for Python 2.7 only.`. I try to fix that install all required dependency from  `requirements.txt`, but not helped. I try on `Python 2.7` and with `Python 3.7`.

For now I don't know how bite this problem. Someone have idea or hint?

Elastic stack versions `7.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set python2 as default

```sh
##  i am using python2.7 for python2
##  and python3.5 for python3
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

you may also need to check if the right pip is installed for the right python version

Comment: As I wrote, unfortunetly, doesnt work this way. I made scripts manually.

Comment: i think, you executed the command outside the filebeat directory

Comment: Thanks for try to help. No, I run from filebeat directory.